OpenSSH: Suddenly can't login with default (ED25519) key; server prompts password; other keys work? Is the problem on the Server or the Client?
I have a server running Linux 6.6.32, OpenSSH_9.7p1, and OpenSSL 3.0.13 (30 Jan 2024). All of a sudden, after a reboot, the server won't accept my ED25519-key anymore when I log in into it from my main laptop. In the following I refer to S when I talk about the server and L when I talk about that laptop.
A login from L to S on the command line results in Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). If I (temporarily) allow password login on S, I get prompted with a password instead.
Here are all findings I currently have:

The public key of the default SSH key on L is definitely deployed to S in /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/<username>
From L I still can ssh to a variety of other machines with the same Linux and OpenSSH versions using the same ed25519 key, without any problem.
From another laptop, I successfully can connect to S using the default ED25519 key of that laptop.
If I create additional SSH keys on L and deploy the corresponding public keys to S, I can successfully connect by using:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/test_rsa_key user@S
ssh -i ~/.ssh/test_ed25519_key user@S


explicitly using the default key on L (ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 user@S) doesn't work
If I add the key with the login trouble from L to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on S it works! But the other keys I have for the user also work if they are just in /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/<username>. It also doesn't have to do anything with the order.

From journalctl -u sshd on S I can see that failed login attempts with my default key result in:
May 29 16:25:15 S sshd[1836]: Connection closed by authenticating user <user> 81.201.150.231 port 49240 [preauth]
May 29 16:25:33 S sshd[1839]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for <user> from 81.201.150.231

At this point, I can't say if it something on the client-side or the server-side. My client also uses the openssh package in version 9.7p1.
This is the content of /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
GatewayPorts no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
KexAlgorithms sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
LogLevel INFO
Macs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
PrintMotd no
StrictModes yes
UseDns no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding no
Banner none

AddressFamily any
Port 22

Subsystem sftp /nix/store/0g1s8yd0biawp32fl3i7kdbi219jx6aq-openssh-9.7p1/libexec/sftp-server

AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u


HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

I have years of experience with ssh, Linux, and NixOS (the Linux distribution on all my machines). But also rolling back to older NixOS generations / versions didn't change anything here in that case. Very confusing - especially as it is only this very limited case that doesn't work anymore!

What happens when you append the public key to $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server? Any unusual output when you add -vvv to the ssh command invocation?

Also, what's inside /etc/ssh/sshd_config (on the server)? Did it change after update?

Running Debian here rather than NixOS, but to make certificate authentication work the way you've described I needed to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u. Has that second search location maybe been removed in a recent update?

I've added the content of /etc/ssh/sshd_config to my post. Further: If I add the key from L to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on S, it works! Very strange, as the other keys I've successfully tested have also been only added to /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/<username>. I also tested whether the order of my keys in /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/<username> makes a different - but it does not. Also, the key in /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/<username> that doesn't work is definitely the same as the one I add to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Scrabbling for ideas here. Permissions/ownerships for the authorised_keys.d directory  (and its parents) and on the username files?

"PAM: Authentication failure for " - if you haven't already done so, it would be worth you cross-checking the PAM files. Start with /etc/pam.d/ssh (or sshd) and ensure it matches with one of your working systems. Likewise for any included files. Also check the user account hasn't got something silly like an expired date (passwd -S {username}). I don't think this will present any issues as you've already noted you can log in if you put the key in the user's directory. To me that suggests permissions/ownerships are the more likely culprit

Please update the question to contain an actual question. For example: "is this issue related to the server or the client"?

Thanks everyone. I found the solution - it was a very subtle unintentional configuration failure. I added it below.

I found the root cause. NixOS 24.05 and openssh work just fine, both on S and L. The problem was a unfortunate commit with a very subtle change in the NixOS configuration files for S where the accepted keys are defined (reference).
The commit style: fmt and typos, for which I executed $ typos -w (reference), changed the public SSH key for my user on L in the NixOS configuration for S from
"ssh-ed25519 ***Oen*** user@machine
to
"ssh-ed25519 ***One*** user@machine
This was not obvious in the diff view of the long string. So, NixOS put the now wrong SSH key into /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/<username> on S when the configuration was applied. As I never fully compared the public ssh key (actual vs expected) but only the begin and the end of the string, and also the git history didn't look suspicious on a first glance, I didn't expect the error to be there. Today I had a second look at the git history and yeah..
This was a very subtle bug. The proper fix is to revert that change from the commit and configure typos in a way that it ignores SSH keys / doesn't try to find typos in (a substring of) a key.
Thanks everyone for their input!

Related answer: https://superuser.com/a/1723412
Quote:

If the mode of "authorized_keys" is 600 and the file's owner is not the UID of the authenticating user, the authentication should fail.

As an aside, you don't need %h/ in front of the path given as an argument to AuthorizedKeysFile, as relative paths are taken as being relative to the user's home directory, so:
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

A test on Alpine Linux v3.19 seems to confirm that file permissions on the file given as AuthorizedKeysFile are important. If the owner of /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/username is username, where username is the authenticating user (and the permissions are -rw------- = 600), then the authentication is successful. If the owner is root, then it fails (unless, of course, one is authenticating as root and PermitRootLogin is set to yes).

S sshd[1836]: Connection closed by authenticating user <user> 81.201.150.231 port 49240 [preauth]

From the server S's viewpoint, the client suddenly closed the connection in mid-authentication.
So the error suggests a possible client-side issue... as far as the server sees it.
Check the permissions of any key files and the directories they're in. SSH tends to ignore any key files that are insufficiently secure.
Commands like namei -mov $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519 (client-side) and namei -mov /etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/username (server-side) should display the permissions of the file and all its parent directories at once, which might be useful in detecting insecure directories anywhere on the directory path, just like SSH does.
But if the client sees it as the server closing the connection, then there is something in the middle cutting the connection.
Could it be possible there might be a firewall or SSH proxy device somewhere in between S and L that is configured to detect SSH connections by contents, and terminate the connection once it knows for sure the protocol is SSH, or if encountering a SSH protocol feature it doesn't know how to handle?
(If there seems to be such a device with no legitimate reason for it, it might mean your connection is being Man-in-the-middle attacked. If you think this might be the case, and you are a member of an organization which has dedicated Information Security people, this would be time to call them and report what you're seeing.)
